# wood peeling with a knife and curling its chips

Tags: modeling, animation

Is it possible to animate the process of wood peeling with a knife and curling its chips in Blender? If yes, do you know with which modules or functions of Blender it can be simulated?

For example, animating the zoom-in of the process that a sharp knife removes layer by layer of wood and the chips curls.

For example in the following movie, in 4:22 time frame, it shows from the backside and not the real peeling process, but it shows the overview of the peeling:

https://youtu.be/aqz-KE-bpKQ?t=259

or in the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CnEE.jpg) from the above movie, you can understand what I meant.
Thanks for any hints on how to do the zoom-in of the process of the peeling with a knife or any tutorial close to that or name of any option which may help.

In this Blender file [image], you can find out what I tried and it did not work out:

Kind regards

[image: Wood peeling process, but it does not show the real process of removing the wood]

The second round of the question:

Dear @lemon, thanks so much for your great help. I tried to replicate what you guided me, but I have some challenges. I would be grateful if you once more have a look to this new file [link] (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/QQpq3s8k/) . I do apologize for my basic questions. If I have to read some parts of the documentation, please also inform me. Here I explain what I did. May be I do not see some points:
1- for the drawing of the main rod the wood, I use (Add, Mesh, Cylender) then because the automatic cylinder is in z direction I have no way except rotating in x and z, 90 degree. I use also “cap fill type” of “Ngon”. I used also 50 Vertices to have a fine surface.
The first question: When I look at your model, you have different type of “Cap Fill Type”. One side is open, one side has rounded edges, and in the center a rounded shape. Did you use “”Bevel” for making the round edges and deletes one face of the cap? Is it important for this simulation?
2-I also used “loop cut”, to partion it to make fine chip, is it necessary?
3-I did not understand how to position “empty”and the “cube” of the cutter on the same coordinate system. I moved the “empty” by hand and also on the menue of “transformation” to give the approximate coordinate and positioned it somewhere on the edge similar to yours. Did I do a mistake?
4- is the size of the empty important? (its scale?)
5-my main question is how did you manage it that the form of the curled chip does not become weird after cutting? In my model it changes and becomes thick after separating
Thanks so much for your time and help

Comment: Your file reworked a bit (still needs tuning): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ek3nLog9/ . Mainly axis are different and the usage of an empty to bend. Keep in mind this is an "effect" which need to be handled differently when the chip goes too far.

Comment: @lemon, thanks so much for your helps, I worked on your guidelines and I have some questions which I asked in the main question above! (because of the limitation of the characters here). I would be grateful if you answer. thanks

Comment: Well... many questions... one side is open just because it was invisible and not the direct subject (lazziness no more). Bevel, yes. I don't think its really important but boolean may have issues depending on the topology. About loop cuts, give it a try (reason: be able to bend the cut). From your file: avoid working with objects that are scaled (and unevenly). Also the cut is not straight along an axis (it goes down, so this is not a straight cut). Above all that, the setting is a way to do it (for a little part of the global animation), there may be others ie compositing, shape keys...).

Comment: About the "weird" cutting: in some limits, that works. After that you should managed it differently as I don't think there is an easy way to play with the chip too far from the rod. Again don't think I provided the ideal way to do it. It is just a way with its limitations.

Comment: Your file updated: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3jgEB4bb/ Main aspects: the empty is animated also to limit the weird effect and the cut is straight along the cutter X axis.

Comment: Or maybe this one is better (the empty is animated in two steps): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/A0GD4kys/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An opportunity to test the 2.91 boolean modifier options...

[image]

There are two rods in the scene (a copy of the first one but different material), one for what we see as the rod and another for the cut.

The first one has a boolean modifier set to *"exact"*:

[image]

The second a boolean and a simple deform (*"bend"*) modifier driven by the empty (which is parented to the cube). But here the boolean is set to *"fast"* because if the shape is plain, simple deform will transform it badly.

The cutting cube is parent of an empty that is used as pivot point for the bending.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Neat! I'm a Boolean convert! Tried this without, in 290, and it 'worked', but the answer would have taken 2 pages of description.

Comment: @RobinBetts, more a test case than a practical way of doing the complete animation, though.

Comment: What's wrong with it? ... I suppose you would need to sub in a dupe of the chip to have it fly away.. but any method would need that?

Comment: @RobinBetts, mainly because you'll need many rods to make a complete spike. Or as you say for the chip, make dupe parts.

Comment: @lemon, thanks for your comments, It seems there is a small trick that I cannot make it curling (bending), as you explained in your post and also showed in your files! May I ask you to have a look to this file and mention why it does not bend as you mentioned?!  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2EmlpZee" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2EmlpZee/)

Comment: In the other file (the one I provided above) there is an empty placed at the head of the cutter. The empty is visible in the images above. Also in your file the rods are scaled and the axis for the empty is not the same (X instead of Y). Also avoid working with object the are scaled of rotated if not needed.